# MVC - Asp.net identity CreateAsync method issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

-> We are using the asp.net identity for creating users.
-> user is creating but throwing error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
-> its calling two times ?

Comment: Can you please share more details so i can help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.